# Efficiently substract from matrix columnwise

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I have a rather simple problem and was wondering whether some of you guys know a very efficient (=fast) solution for this:

I have two matrices `mat` and `arr` and want to accomplish the following: Take every column of `arr` and substract it from `mat`. Then take the logarithm of one minus the absolute value of the difference. That's it. Right now, I'm using `sapply` (see below), but I'm pretty sure that it's possible to do it faster (maybe using `sweep`?)

Code:

```
mat <- matrix(.3, nrow=10, ncol = 4)
arr <- matrix(.1, nrow=10, ncol = 10000)
i <- ncol(arr)
result <- sapply(1:i, function(ii) (log(1-abs(mat-arr[,ii]))))
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: 10,000 cols takes 0.05 seconds over here, 100,000 just over a second. I wouldn't be too concerned with your current solution.

Comment: It's part of an iterative process and it is accountable for around 55% of the time that the process takes. Right now I'm up to 4 days of total processing time, so every millisecond counts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replicate and then do a difference

```
result2 <- matrix(log(1- abs(rep(mat, ncol(arr)) - 
                      rep(arr, ncol(mat)))), ncol = i) 
identical(result, result2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Cool, that's around 50% faster than my solution, thanks!